# How do I solve a function with x^2 and x^-1 to x?

Tags: functional-analysis, analytic-geometry, exponentiation

We got two functions:

1. $f(x)=ax^2+b$
2. $g(x)=x^{-1}=1/x$

I know that they are touching each other in $x=1$. Now I can find out the values for $a$ and $b$ in $f(x)$.

1. Set the derivative of both functions equal $f'(1)=g'(1)$ to get $a$
   $$\begin{align}&f'(x)=2ax; g'(x)=x^{-2}\\
   \implies& 2a(1)=(1)^{-2}\\
   \implies& a = -\frac12\end{align}$$
2. Set the base functions equal $f(1)=g(1)$ to get $b$

$$\begin{align}&f(x)=-\frac12x^2+b\\
\implies & -\frac12(1)+b=(1)^{-1}\\
\implies & b = \frac32\end{align}$$
3. Control the result (this is were my issue is)
$$\begin{align}&f(x)=g(x)\\
\implies&-\frac12x^2+\frac32=x^{-1} &|& \text{ subract } x^{-1}\\
\Longleftrightarrow& -\frac12x^2-x^{-1}+\frac32=0 &|&\text{ multiply by } -2\\
\Longleftrightarrow& x^2-2x^{-1}-3=0\end{align}$$

I now would like to get $x=1$ to control mathematically if my above result is valid.

But I have no idea how I could solve a function with two powers

Comment: luckily just not on the paper just in the thread :) but thanks for reminding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to solve a polynomial of third degree. While it can be [solved](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_of_roots), there is no need to. If you just want to check your result, it's okay to substitute 1 for x and try. Your solutions are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your last line should read $x^2+2x^{-1}-3=0$.
This is $\frac{x^3-2-3x}x=\frac{(x-1)(x^2+x-2)}x=\frac{(x-1)(x-1)(x+2)}x$. The factor $(x-1)$ occuring quadratic implies touching.
Anyway, to control the result you could explicitly calculate $f(1), f'(1), g(1), g'(1)$ and check for equality.